# Which port of esxi server i can use with veeam backup

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I have `esxi server` on my server.

I can connect to it via vsphere client successfully.

I have just installed veeam free backup and it tries to connect via same ip and port `443`

But it says can't connect.

Which port i need to use for esxi? vsphere client is working fine on my windows

Also **Does Veeam connect directly to esxi or i need to install vcenter server**

[image]

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.veeam.com/kb1518

Comment: @joeqwerty i have read that but from esxi side how can i find which port number to use and if its open or not